# How to get consecutive pairs in pandas data frame and find the date difference for valid pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

**Input Data:**

| sn | fruits | Quality | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | A | 2022-09-01 |
| 2 | Apple | A | 2022-08-15 |
| 3 | Apple | A | 2022-07-15 |
| 4 | Apple | B | 2022-06-01 |
| 5 | Apple | A | 2022-05-15 |
| 6 | Apple | A | 2022-04-15 |
| 7 | Banana | A | 2022-08-15 |
| 8 | Orange | A | 2022-08-15 |

Get the average date diff for each type of fruit, only if quality=A and there are consecutive record with quality A.

If there are three rows of A quality only first 2 make valid pair. Third one is not valid pair as 4th record is quality=B

So in above data we have 2 valid pairs for Apple 1st pair= (1,2) = 15days date diff and 2nd pair = (5,6) = 15days diff so **avg for apple is 15days**

**Expected output**

| fruits | avg time diff |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 15 days |
| Banana | null |
| Orange | null |

How can I do this without using any looping in pandas dataframe?